# How does this firebase-security rule work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I try to learn how this code sample work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Correct me now but, is this a correct struktur and with the above rule, `Bob doe`can never write to `John Doe` data?

```
  "users": {
    "This is the id in firebase for Bob doe": {
      "name ": "Bob doe",
      "time": 1459361875337
    },
    "This is the id in firebase for John doe": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "time": 1459361875337
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the rules as you have them only the user whose uid is `This is the id in firebase for John doe` can write data under that node indeed.

Comment: Thank God I start to get it, you rock!